# Matlab finding best fit line from scatter plot but exclude some data points

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot

I use Matlab to find the best fit line from a scatter plot, but I need to delete some data points. For example I am trying to find the best fit line of

x = [10 70 15 35 55 20 45 30];
y = [40 160 400 90 500 60 110 800];

Now I need to delete all y points that value is over 300, and of course deleting corresponding x points, and then make a scatter plot and find the best fit line. So how to implement this?

Comment: what did you try? show us your code. this isn't a place where you come and get people to do your homework for you. it's trivial. i could do it in about 60 seconds, but I'm annoyed at the explicit lack of effort on your part.

Comment: Yes, I'll agree it's a bad question. It's answered cause it was relatively simple and this is a useful example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I need to delete all y points that value is over 300, and of course deleting corresponding x points,

There is standard Matlab trick - **Logical Indexing** (see for example  in [matrix-indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)):

```
x = [10 70 15 35 55 20 45 30]; y = [40 160 400 90 500 60 110 800];
filter = (y<300);
y1 = y(filter);
x1 = x(filter);
plot(x,y,'+b',x1,y1,'or');
```

You can use **polyfit** ([Matlab Doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html?searchHighlight=polyfit)) function for linear fit:

```
ff=polyfit(x1,y1,1);
plot(x,y,'*b',x1,y1,'or',x1,ff(1)*x1 + ff(2),'-g');
grid on;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to logically filter the dataset, then plot it.
NOTE: Data should be in column format. If it isn't, rotate like `x'`.

```
filter = (y<300);
x = x.*filter;
x = [zeros(length(x),1),x]; % this is to get the b(0) coefficient
y = y.*filter;

b = x\y;
x = x(:,2); % cleaning up column of zeros

plot(x,y,'bo')
hold on
plot([min(x),max(x)],(b(1)+b(2))*[min(x),max(x)])
hold off
axis tight
```

Comment: To create test data for this: `y = rand(10,1)*400;`